# Modelling 'has a' relationship

Tags: python

I'm attempting to model this JSON describing a Car :

```
{
colour : "green"
specs : {
brakes : "good brakes"
}
}
```

A car 'has a' relationship with specs. Here is how I implement:

```
import json

class Car :
    def __init__(self , colour, specs):
        self.colour = colour
        self.specs = specs

class Specs : 
    def __init__(self , brakes):
        self.brakes = brakes
        

specs = Specs("good brakes")
car = Car("Green" , specs) 

print(json.dumps(car.__dict__))
```

which returns:

```
TypeError: Object of type Specs is not JSON serializable
```

In order to model the "has a" relationship should I create my own to_json function in  `Car`?

Comment: Your class design indeed models the relationship IMO.  But that's not the problem you're having.  A generic Python object cannot, in general, be JSON serialized without some extra work.  Adding a "to_json" function won't help.  There are illustrations for some simple cases in the standard docs.  What exactly do you want help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider having an encoder class for your Car class like below

```
In [8]: import json
   ...:
   ...: class Car :
   ...:     def __init__(self , colour, specs):
   ...:         self.colour = colour
   ...:         self.specs = specs
   ...:
   ...: class Specs :
   ...:     def __init__(self , brakes):
   ...:         self.brakes = brakes
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: specs = Specs("good brakes")
   ...: car = Car("Green" , specs)
   ...:

In [9]:

In [10]: from json import JSONEncoder
    ...:

In [11]: class CarEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    ...:         def default(self, o):
    ...:             op =  o.__dict__
    ...:             op['specs'] =  o.specs.__dict__
    ...:             return op
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:

In [12]: json.dumps(car, cls=CarEncoder)
Out[12]: '{"colour": "Green", "specs": {"brakes": "good brakes"}}'

In [13]:
```

The CarEncoder's default method will be called by json.dumps. There i have replaced specs with the dictionary of specs..

Answer (score 1):

A modification of your method to check to see if sub-object have dicts will work in this, and other simple cases. For example:

```py
def to_dict(obj):
    """Convert objects with a '__dict__' method into nested dicts."""

    return {
        key: to_dict(value) if hasattr(value, '__dict__') else value
        for key, value in obj.__dict__.items()
    }


print(json.dumps(to_dict(car)))
```

There are many cases where this will fall down though:

- If you use `__slots__` in your object
- If you want to support properties or lists

You could extend the method to try and account for each of these, but it might be time to bite the bullet and either use a serialisation library (as suggested elsewhere), or write your own object specific `to_dict()` methods as you suggested.